# Where is iPhone Configuration Utility tool for Mac Sierra?

Tags: macos, ipcu

I was looking for IPCU for managing my provisioning profiles on my latest Mac OS 10.12.4 Sierra, but there is no valid dmg available on the internet. Is that available, or is there some another tool for doing the same?

Answer (score 2):

Apple Configurator is the replacement for iPhone Configuration Utility:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12

Comment: Apple Configurator is definitely helpful for adding provisioning profiles for iPhone, iPad. But, I need an app for managing prov. profiles on Mac like  IPCU.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh Yes, please check my answer above and try. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install from here: https://en.freedownloadmanager.org/Mac-OS/iPhone-Configuration-Utility-FREE.html . On installation, it shows me some error. But when I Spotlight Search, I can see IPCU installed on my mac(initially there was no IPCU on my mac). You can try the same.

Comment: not working on mojave :(, is there any other app for managing profiles? Apple Configurator not dealing with profiles on your mac.